# Best way to make a request to external web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, networking, cross-domain

So, I have this web application that shows network products for a specific network. The web server is not inside the network, so in order to show the visitor what network services he or she can order, I need to identify their computer inside the network.

So, I've been doing this with an iframe, which loads a specific in-network URL provided by my clients. This in-network URL will identify the visiting browser and then redirect it (inside the iframe) to a resource on my web service, with attached identification details.

For identification to occur, the in-network web server needs to receive a HTTP request from the visitor, but is this really the best way to handle this? Ajax cross domain is a bit of a mess as far as I'm aware, but I think iframe cross domain is equally shaky, or?

How would you solve this? The chain of events needs to be:

1. visitor visits **my.web.com/services**
2. visitor is sent to **client.network.com/identify**
3. Which redirects to **my.web.com/identifier?id=XXYY**

Now I can set a cookie for **my.web.com** on the user browser that their id is "XXYY" (or update member profile if logged in). Obviously this request needs to be asynchronous since the in-network web server may be slow to respond, so just a normal redirect is off the table.

Comment: "Ajax cross domain is a bit of a mess as far as I'm aware" — CORS is well documented and well supported, so no.

Comment: "I think iframe cross domain is equally shaky" — `postMessage` is well document and well supported, so no.